# Can't update datasource from gridview update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

Trying to update my DB from the edit/update functionality of a GridView. What ever I try, I can't seem to be working.

How can I update my SQLDatasource using the information entered in the GridView edit textbox?

Here is what I have:

.cs:

```
                    DS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tbSystems SET Systems = @Systems WHERE id = @id";
                    DS.Update();
```

.aspx:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gv1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CellPadding="2"
                    DataKeyNames="id"
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
                    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                    OnRowDeleting="gv1_RowDeleting"
                    OnRowDeleted="gv1_RowDeleted"
                    OnRowUpdating="gv1_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="gv1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdated="gv1_RowUpdated">
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>">
                     <UpdateParameters>
                         <asp:Parameter Name="Systems" Type="String" />
                     </UpdateParameters>
                 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

1. Shouldn't the id variable be declared already since I have it
   declared in the DataKeyNames of the GridView or should I create an update parameter in the SQLDataSource?
2. How do I get the new value in the textbox of the GridView? This line of code always give the old value regardless in which event (edit event, updating event or updated event) I put it in:

   Response.Write(((TextBox)gv1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text);
3. How do I manage the @variables?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any code to connect a `GridView` to a `SqlDataSource` control. Just set the relevant properties on the controls and it will just work:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="DS"
    DataKeyNames="id"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
/>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tbSystems"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE tbSystems SET Systems = @Systems WHERE id = @id"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE tbSystems WHERE id = @id"
>
     <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Systems" Type="String" />
     </UpdateParameters>
     <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The important properties are:

- [`DataSourceID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.datasourceid.aspx) - connects the `GridView` to the `SqlDataSource`;
- [`SelectCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand.aspx) - specifies the SQL command used to fill the `GridView`;
- [`UpdateCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx) - specifies the SQL command used to update a record;
- [`UpdateParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters.aspx) - defines the parameters passed to the `UpdateCommand`;
- [`DeleteCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand.aspx) - specifies the SQL command used to delete a record;
- [`DeleteParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deleteparameters.aspx) - defines the parameters passed to the `DeleteCommand`;

With those properties in place, you can get rid of the event handlers in the code-behind. The data source control will take care of everything for you.

[ASP.NET Data-Bound Web Server Controls Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx)
[Data Source Controls Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227679.aspx)

Comment: This is working as you explained. Thanks. I'll end this with a last question: This works with a connection between a gridview and a SQLDataSource. My page has buttons accessing different DB tables. In this scenario, would you create x number of SQLdatasources and change the gridview datasourceID when needed or would you go with some other option?

Comment: @Rimo72: I'd be inclined to have a separate `SqlDataSource` and `GridView` for each table, and use something like [a `MultiView` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview(v=vs.110).aspx) to only show the current grid.

Comment: What always trips me up is that in order for update, insert, or delete to work automatically, you must include the parameter Type, but if you use the GUI to set up the data source queries, it doesn't automatically include or prompt you to specify it. It's buried under Advanced, which seems to imply the defaults work most of the time/in the most basic case - and they don't.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Naveen and lots of tweeking, I finally got to make it work. Here is how I did it. It may not be the best practices but it works.

Put the SQLDataSource in a Session. I don't knkow if this is the right thing to do, however it is the only way I found to catch the value of the gridview edit textbox.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
                DS.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbSystems";
                Session["myDS"] = DS;
                BindData();
}
```

Created a BindData function: (gv1 being my GridView)

```
private void BindData()
        {
            gv1.DataSource = Session["myDS"];
            gv1.DataBind();
        }
```

In the RowEditing function, I've changed the gv1 edit index to the event new edit index.

```
protected void gv1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gv1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            //Bind data to the GridView control.
            BindData();
```

And this is the update code.

```
protected void gv1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

                    DS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tbSystems SET Systems = @Systems WHERE id = @id";
                    var id = gv1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["id"];
                    var systems = ((TextBox)gv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
                    DS.UpdateParameters.Add("id",id.ToString());
                    DS.UpdateParameters.Add("Systems",systems);
                    DS.Update();
                    gv1.EditIndex = -1;
                    BindData();
        }
```

Hopefully this will help some of you.

Thanks,

Comment: Storing a control in the session state is an *extremely* bad idea. You don't need any of the code-behind methods you've posted - just set the relevant properties on the `SqlDataSource` control.

Comment: Like I said not sure it is the right thing to do. Been working on this for a week now this is the only way I got it to work. What would you change from the above code to make it proper coding? Can you help?

Comment: I've posted an answer which should help. Basically, you don't need any code to hook the grid and the data source control together. That was the main benefit of the data source controls.

Comment: The accepted answer above is correct, however fyi you can get the grid view's data source in the RowUpdating event with ((GridView)sender).DataSourceObject.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the id variable be declared already since I have it declared
>   in the DataKeyNames of the GridView or should I create an update
>   parameter in the SQLDataSource?

No. You must fetch the value like this

```
var id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["id"];
```

> How do I get the new value in the textbox of the GridView? This line
>   of code always give the old value regardless in which event (edit
>   event, updating event or updated event) I put it in

You should be using the RowUpdating event. [MSDN sample code here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx).

> How do I manage the @variables?

```
var systems = ((TextBox)gv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
DS.UpdateParameters.Add("@id", id);
DS.UpdateParameters.Add("@Systems", systems);
```

Comment: Naveen, thanks for the feedback. I followed your guidance and it gives me this error.  Must declare the scalar variable "@Systems". Can I assume that my SQL query is missing a declaration? Should I add a DECLARE in my SQL query?

Comment: Removed the @ in the Add parameter and corrected the error. How ever, this line: `var systems = ((TextBox)gv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;` gives me the old value for the cell not the new one. Been searching for this issue for a while. It doesn't give me the data of the textbox.

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, for people who aren't using a data source and can't rely on the default binding behaviour, the GridViewUpdateEventArgs in the OnRowUpdating handler contains the new values. `var val = e.NewValues[0]`. (if you do need to go into the row, use FindControl("TextBox1") rather than Controls[0] - I believe the Controls collection includes both the Vew and Edit templates.